# How does the fitness flex define "active time"

Tags: fitbit

It measures "very active time" in addition to steps, but I have no idea what that means.  Assuming it's based on "lots of arm movement, does that mean that it'll pick up jogging, but not a stationary bike?  Is there some way to tell it I'm (finally, at long last) working out?

Comment: I have had my fitbit for a little over week now and have done a duathlon and a 12k as well as other training runs - my Fitbit has yet to acknowledge that I have indeed had some "very active" minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the Fitbit help pages:](https://help.fitbit.com/customer/portal/articles/1020095-what-are-%22very-active-minutes%22-)

> You earn "Very Active Minutes" when you wear your Fitbit while doing
>   cardio workouts and high intensity activities like jogging, running,
>   aerobics, biking, rowing, or anything where you are working up a
>   sweat.
>
> By default, you are given a starting goal of 30 Very Active Minutes a
>   day based on the Center for Disease Control's recommendation of 20-30
>   minutes of daily moderate-to-intense activity. You can always change
>   your Very Active Minutes goal to meet your personal needs.

Which doesn't tell us much, though I suspect it should be able to pick up forward accelerations.

Other help topic mention your concern [regarding cycling:](https://help.fitbit.com/customer/portal/articles/176113-does-the-fitbit-tracker-accurately-track-calories-from-cycling-and-biking-)

> All Fitbit trackers are optimized for walking, running, and general
>   household and lifestyle activities.  It will not be as accurate for
>   activities like biking, but will record that your were active if you
>   wear your tracker during a non-walking or running activity.   For
>   increased accuracy, go to: http://www.fitbit.com/activities or click
>   the "log activity" icon from your Dashboard to manually log activities
>   like cycling. This will allow for a more accurate estimated calorie
>   burn for workouts like cycling to be included in your daily totals.
>   Our online database of workouts makes it easy to save and access your
>   favorite activities.

[and:](https://help.fitbit.com/customer/portal/articles/176113-does-the-fitbit-tracker-accurately-track-calories-from-cycling-and-biking-)

> All Fitbit trackers are optimized for walking, running, and general
>   household and lifestyle activities.  It will not be as accurate for
>   activities like biking, but will record that your were active if you
>   wear your tracker during a non-walking or running activity.   For
>   increased accuracy, go to: http://www.fitbit.com/activities or click
>   the "log activity" icon from your Dashboard to manually log activities
>   like cycling. This will allow for a more accurate estimated calorie
>   burn for workouts like cycling to be included in your daily totals.
>   Our online database of workouts makes it easy to save and access your
>   favorite activities.

Here's more information [regarding manual logging](https://help.fitbit.com/customer/portal/articles/413311-activity-logging).

Given that the Fitbit Flex uses a 3-axial accelerometer, I reckon it starts counting Very Active Minutes as soon as it notices a deviation from patterns of known activities such as normal walking, sitting or lying down/sleep. Especially if you fall into a repetitive pattern, it should be able to reliably determine you're doing something.

My advice for cycling: put the wristband around your ankles, they might record awkward data, but it'll surely be very reliable.

Answer (score -1):

So how is weight training not considered active minutes? When I used to log my activities (some training sessions lasting up to 90 minutes at medium-to-high intensity) it counted the time. The latest update is so far from truthful that it shouldn't be considered indicative of physical activity. I sweat buckets when I train so the logic you provide is deeply flawed.